# Non-recursive means of printing a list in Python

Tags: python, recursion

Is there a way to perform the following in a non-recursive fashion:

```
my_list = [
    "level 1-1",
    "level 1-2",
    "level 1-3",
        [
            "level 2-1",
            "level 2-2",
            "level 2-3",
            [
                "level 3-1",
                "level 3-2"
            ]
        ],
    "level 1-4",
    "level 1-5"
    ]


def print_list(the_list, indent_level=0):
    for item in the_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            print_list(item, indent_level + 1)
        else:
            print "\t" * indent_level, item


print_list(my_list)
```

Comment: is it a puzzle or is it really needed some place? i am curious.

Comment: Just trying to find the most efficient of solving a problem like this. It's not a puzzle, but the code I provided IS just an example.

Comment: It's also a standard first- or second-year CS algorithm.  :)

Comment: Also note that doing this iteratively is not necessarily faster than doing it recursively.  In fact, in a quick test (100k runs with no output), your code is the fastest: 1600ms; mine's 1750, and Martin's is 2000ms.  The balance may be different with graph with a lot of non-leaf nodes, since it would be recursing more.

Comment: You don't really buy much by doing it non-recursively, since you cannot avoid having a stack around (assuming potentially unlimited depth).

Comment: You can gain in principle, because your own stack doesn't need to hold as much data as a stack frame.  In practice, at least in Python, it's probably going to be a wash at best.  If you're actually doing real work down on the leaf nodes, though, it's nice for exception traces to not spit out fifty recursive stack frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
stack = [(my_list, -1)]
while stack:
    item, level = stack.pop()

    if isinstance(item, list):
        for i in reversed(item):
            stack.append((i, level+1))
    else:
        print "\t" * level, item
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_list(the_list, indent_level=0):
    stack = [iter(the_list)]
    while stack:
        try:
            item = stack[-1].next()
        except StopIteration:
            stack.pop()
            indent_level -= 1
            continue
        if isinstance(item, list):
            indent_level += 1
            stack.append(iter(item))
        else:
            print "\t" * indent_level, item
```

Comment: A stack of iterators--cute.  I like mine a bit better (concise, and slightly faster--for me, anyway), but this one avoids making a copy of the whole tree, which might be helpful if it's very large and broad.  You'd probably need millions of nodes for it to matter, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of Martin Löwis' version that uses `for/else` instead of manually catching `StopIteration`, and `len(stack)` instead of keeping track of the indent level.

```
def print_list(the_list):
    stack = [iter(the_list)]
    while stack:
        for item in stack[-1]:
            if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
                stack.append(iter(item))
                break
            else:
                print '\t' * (len(stack)-1), item
        else:
            stack.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this depens on the input not containing tuples.

```
l1 = my_list
done = False

# Repeatedly turn the list elements into tuples of the form
# (indent, item) until there are no more lists.
while not done:
    done = True
    l2 = []
    for item in l1:
        if isinstance(item,tuple):
            indent = item[0]
            item = item[1]
        else:
            indent = 0
        if isinstance(item,list):
            l2.extend( zip( (indent + 1,) * len(item), item) )
            done = False
        else:
            l2.append((indent,item))
    l1 = l2

for indent, item in l1:
    print "\t" * indent, item
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has given solutions which are

- production ready
- use stack, so has same problem as recursion
- or go thru list multiple time

Here is a solution lateral solution :)

- not production ready but fun
- no stack or anything like that, no lists in sight

--

```
def my_print(the_list):
    level = -1
    out = []
    levelUp="levelup"
    levelDown="leveldown"

    s =  repr(the_list).replace("', '","\n").replace(
        "', ['", "\n%s\n"%levelUp).replace("['", "\n%s\n"%levelUp).replace(
        "']", "\n%s\n"%levelDown).replace("], '", "\n%s\n"%levelDown)

    for line in s.splitlines():
        if not line: continue
        if line == levelUp:
            level+=1
        elif line == levelDown:
            level-=1
        else:
            print "\t"*level,line

my_print(my_list)
```

It assumes the your list text will not have some special substrings.